# AccessDeniedException when changed a cljs file

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying out the tutorials in 
https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/second-edition/tutorial-02.md

I started it by using the command

```
boot serve -d target watch cljs target -d target
```

When I changed the cljs file, I see this exception

> Writing main.cljs.edn...
>   Compiling ClojureScript...
>   ò main.js
>   Writing target dir(s)...
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: 
> target\main.out\modern_cljs\core.js
>       java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: target\main.out\modern_cljs\core.js
>       file: "target\main.out\modern_cljs\core.js"

my `boot.properties` contains:

```
#http://boot-clj.com
#Tue Jan 03 23:11:53 CST 2017
BOOT_CLOJURE_NAME=org.clojure/clojure
BOOT_CLOJURE_VERSION=1.8.0
BOOT_VERSION=2.5.5
BOOT_EMIT_TARGET=no
BOOT_HOME=D:/onemoretime/temp
```

the problem happens without the `BOOT_HOME` property too.

Comment: Why are you using -d flag twice? Is you directory really named "target"? Perhaps you want to do `boot serve -d target watch reload cljs target`?